# jq: filter array and project other field

Tags: jq

Here my document:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "9f0e27fe-3b8f-4857-8e1d-e57e7a3f4c31",
    "identifier": [
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.19126.3"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "Y3454867M"
        }
      },
      {
        "system": {
          "value": "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.10.2"
        },
        "value": {
          "value": "108505134"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to pick only `.identifier[where .system.value == "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.19126.3"]` and project `.identifier.value.value`.

Desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "9f0e27fe-3b8f-4857-8e1d-e57e7a3f4c31",
    "identifier": "Y3454867M"
  }
]
```

I've been playing with `map` and `select` but I don't quite figure out what's the right way to get it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach uses `first` to get the first result, in case there is more than one array item matching the criteria.

```sh
jq --arg v "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.19126.3" '
  map(.identifier |= first(.[] | select(.system.value == $v).value.value))
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "9f0e27fe-3b8f-4857-8e1d-e57e7a3f4c31",
    "identifier": "Y3454867M"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pguO4lrIHY)

Answer (score 1):

Right on the money with the good ol' select tool, since you need data from an arbitrary index. I fumbled a bit before I unwrapped the inner array that gets piped to my select.

`jq -r '.[] | [{id: .id, identifier: .identifier | .[] | select(.system.value | contains("urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.19126.3")) | .value.value }]'`

Still new to jq myself, so any feedback is welcome.